# php вычисления в коде или сохраненные данные в бд

Tags: php, mysql

Есть динамическая страница с кучей данных, многие из которых представляют собой результаты вычисления с использованием десятков данных из бд. Сейчас при загрузке страницы данные берутся из бд (mysql) и каждый раз высчитываются по формулам. Данные в бд обновляются примерно раз в сутки.

Вопрос: ускорится ли загрузка страницы, если вычисления производить при изменении данных и складировать в отдельной таблице бд, а при загрузке страницы брать их вместо того, чтобы каждый раз вычислять?

Насколько я понимаю, это ускорит загрузку, но в гугле сложно сформулировать вопрос и найти конкретный ответ, стоит ли с этим заморочиться.

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: а чем массив не устроил?

Answer (score 2):

Это зависит от многих факторов. В одной ситуации нужно считать на лету, в другой лучше записывать в БД и брать данные из нее. Советую Вам попробовать записать данные в отдельную таблицу и сравнить время загрузки. И уже для себя выбрать, что вам лучше подходить

Answer (score 0):

Вычисления не нагружают систему практический никак. Основная нагрузка идет на работу с бд. Что ты получишь данные и вычислишь их, что запишешь в отдельную таблицу. Разница будет абсолютно не заметной.